# How can I open a text file relative to my MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my bin file I have set up som test data, and I want my application to be able to access logfiles that are stored in `bin/log/log00001.txt`.

However, in my crontroller, when I try to use a TextReader on the following path it goes somewhere else: `new StreamReader("log/log00001.txt")`

How do I read stuff relative to my project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/bin/log/log00001.txt"));
```

Comment: Should be double-quotes.

Answer (score 6):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/some/path/relative/to/your/web/app")
```